# setting a value to the buttons using array in android

Tags: java, android

```
int arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int num=(int)(Math.random()*10);

one.setText(arr1[num]);
one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.second);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hold=((Button)v).getText().toString();
            if((et1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
            et1.setText(hold);
            else
            et2.setText(hold);

        }
    });
```

am i doing the right code for setting a value to the button based on the values in the arrays?
because whenever i run my code my project will unfortunately stop.

Comment: Add logcat output of crash in question.

Answer (score 0):

You must first initialize the button then set its text.

```
Button one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setText(arr1[num]);
```

Comment: i already change my code to that position but still my project unfortunately stops.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change these two lines first.

```
one.setText(arr1[num]);
one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
```

to

```
one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setText(arr1[num]);
```

So your current `NullPointerException` will be solved. Check after that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
one.setText(arr1[num]);
one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
```

**You are using button object "one" before initializing it.**

Change it to:

```
one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
one.setText(arr1[num]);
```

Comment: i already change my code to that position but still my project unfortunately stops.

Comment: then post stacktrace. otherwise it is impossible to help with the provided info

Comment: what do u mean by stacktrace?

Comment: There is something on internet called search engine. Use Bing/Google to find out what stacktrace is!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your button first then set any thing to it-

```
int arr1[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
 int num=(int)(Math.random()*10);

one=(Button)findViewById(R.id.one); //Initialize first
one.setText(arr1[num]);

et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.second);
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        hold=((Button)v).getText().toString();
        if((et1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
        et1.setText(hold);
        else
        et2.setText(hold);

    }
});
```

Comment: i already change my code to that position but still my project unfortunately stops.

Comment: yeah my project still unfortunately stops.

Comment: @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        one.setText(arr1[num]);
        hold=((Button)v).getText().toString();
        if((et1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
        et1.setText(hold);
        else
        et2.setText(hold);
   }
});

i transferred the one.setText(arr1[num]); under the onclick , it runs but after clicking the button one my project stops.